# Use pandas to dynamically convert multiple rows with matching index to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to convert the following data frame from this:

```
class_id     instructor_id
 1                10
 2                10
 2                20
 3                30
 3                40
 3                50
```

to this:

```
class_id   instructor_id   instructor_id_2   instructor_id_3
 1             10
 2             10                   20
 3             30                   40                       50
```

The number of unique instuctor_id columns will be determined dynamically based on the number of instructor_id number associated with each class_id. The instructor_id column names will continue the same pattern of instructor_id_x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `groupby` `apply`+`list` and `apply`+`pd.Series` as:

```
df1 = df.groupby('class_id')['instructor_id'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series)
# alternative df.groupby('class_id')['instructor_id'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.tolist())).unstack()
df1.columns = ['instructor_id']+['instructor_id_'+str(i+1) for i in df1.columns[1:]]
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)

print(df1)
   class_id  instructor_id  instructor_id_2  instructor_id_3
0         1           10.0              NaN              NaN
1         2           10.0             20.0              NaN
2         3           30.0             40.0             50.0
```

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, I only included two columns in my posting.  I actually have two additional columns called 'location_id' and 'course_id'.  How would I go about displaying these columns along with the new dynamically created columns?  I could take the df1 and join it to df on class_id, but I suspect there is a more efficient route by just grouping 'class_id','location_id' and 'couse_id' together.  After trying multiple approaches I keep getting an error:

for example: 
df1 = df.groupby('class_id','location_id','course_id')['instructor_id'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series)

Comment: @RyanFasenmyer Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to verify the case.

Comment: here is a complete example:

Convert from this: 
class_id     course_id     instructor_id     location_id 
 3                300              30                     1
 3                300              40                     1
 3                300              50                     1

Comment: to this: 
class_id   course_id   instructor_id   instructor_id_2   instructor_id_3  location_id
 1               100           10                                                                        1
 2               200           10                   20                                                 1 
 3               300           30                   40                       50                      1

Comment: I see my comments are not formatting properly so you may not be able to see what I'm trying to convey.  I'm not sure what the best practice is for adding a more complete example after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

#### [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) + [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

Here's one way using a `key` helper series:

```
key = df.groupby('class_id')['instructor_id'].cumcount()\
        .add(1).map('Instructor_{}'.format)

res = df.set_index(['class_id', key]).unstack().reset_index()

# clean up column names
res.columns = res.columns.droplevel(0)
res = res.rename(columns={'': 'class_id'})

print(res)

   class_id  Instructor_1  Instructor_2  Instructor_3
0         1          10.0           NaN           NaN
1         2          10.0          20.0           NaN
2         3          30.0          40.0          50.0
```